# How to mark up tales and poems using epub:type?

Tags: epub

The `epub:type` attribute provides 5 values for the content of an e-book: `volume`, `part`, `chapter`, `subchapter` and `division`. I wonder which one is best to use in books which are composed entirely of independent tales or poems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excellent question, and kudos for thinking about the semantics! It's depressing how few people do this.

The best resource for epub:type is the [Strucutral Semantics Vocabulary](http://www.idpf.org/epub/vocab/structure/) from the IDPF. In the "Document Divisions" section, they detail what these divisions are used for:

> **volume:** A component of a collection.
>
> **part:** A major structural division of a piece of writing, typically
> encapsulating a set of related chapters.
>
> **chapter:** A major structural division of a piece of writing.
>
> **subchapter:** A major sub-division of a chapter.
>
> **division:** A major structural division that may also appear as a
> substructure of a part (esp. in legislation).

Each of these divisions should apply to either a `<section>` or a `<body>` element.

For your case of independent tales and poems, I think we can probably rule out `sub-chapter`, unless some of your tales are long enough that they have sections within them that are distinct enough to warrant new levels of headers. My inclination would be to use `chapter` for each item, and potentially `part` if you have relevant content groupings, eg all the tales in one section and all the poems in another. Division seems to be a division that is larger than a chapter but smaller than a part, and volume would be a whole new book. *The Lord of the Rings*, for example, would be three volumes (one for each book), each comprising 2 parts themselves made up of a number of chapters.

It should be noted that at present, there are few devices that make use of epub:type tags at all, and none that I'm aware of that use the document divisions. Adding in the semantics now means that when a reading system does come out that makes use of this information, you'll already be set though, which is nice.